# Gutin and Yeo (2007) style result: classification problem on which greedy decision trees gets the _worst_ performance?

Tags: cart, greedy-algorithm

[Gutin and Yeo (2007, Algo Op Research)](https://www.cs.rhul.ac.uk/%7Egutin/paperstsp/stspgreedy2.pdf) identified a class of optimisation problems (called `anti-matroids`) on which greedy attains the unique *worst* outcome.

user856 presented the construction on math.stackexchange in 2014 [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/935644/511659).

Are there classification problems that correspond to anti-matroids?  Specifically: I am trying to find an example of a classification problem in which a greedy decision tree attains the unique *worst* outcome.

Comment: What evaluation criterion are you using (in building the tree and in evaluating the result - often enough, people use different criteria)? This will likely depend very much on whether you are using [accuracy (you shouldn't)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352) or proper [tag:scoring-rules].

Comment: Thanks!  I'm happy for an example with any performance metric.